# For passing the argument with space in TCL

Tags: networking, tcl

I have to pass this argument: "**ESMContMsg,Sent,PDNConnectivityReject,Network failure**"

But it's taking value up to Network only, since there is space between Network & failure. So how to pass this argument ??

Comment: What is a schema?

Comment: We can say it as a pre-defined variable. Any idea how to pass this argument ?

Comment: Pass it to what from what?

Answer (score 1):

Tcl uses curly braces or double quotes for grouping.  If your argument is grouped inside of double quotes, then you should be okay.

```
proc pass_an_arg {arg1} {
   puts "The argument is: {$arg1}"
}

pass_an_arg "ESMContMsg,Sent,PDNConnectivityReject,Network failure"
--> The argument is: {ESMContMsg,Sent,PDNConnectivityReject,Network failure}
```

but if you don't quote your argument, it's considered as two arguments:

```
pass_an_arg ESMContMsg,Sent,PDNConnectivityReject,Network failure
---> wrong # args: should be "pass_an_arg arg1"
```

Comment: If someone's still having problems with this, there's probably an `eval` being used somewhere without appropriate quoting. Disentangling that sort of thing is _strongly_ advised (as it is indicative of a potential security hole) but can't really be done without looking at the whole program; it's rare that such flaws are only in one place, or that they're the only serious problem.